# making holes with subsurface modifier leaving Ngons

Tags: modeling

I've got mesh which I need to have a specific angle on the edge. I have made the holes into the mesh, which are not causing any shading issue. Is this topology incorrect, or can these Ngons be overlooked? If I did start joining the vertices the angle would alter, therefor I avoided joining them on the end.

[image]

Comment: If your base topology is all quads, subdivision will result in quads. What you see is an "Optimised" mesh. Uncheck "Optimal Display" in the modifier and go into wireframe view to see the actual topology

Comment: Never new about the optimal display, so I guess its ok then: https://ibb.co/WHPLzTf